# 2 compile errors when I try to build MatJuice (cannot find symbol and incompatible types)

Tags: java

I just found this tool, [MatJuice](https://github.com/Sable/matjuice/blob/master/README.md), which could save me days or even weeks of development, but it doesn't compile.

Although I don't know anything about Java, it doesn't look so hairy: the two errors are both located in the same file, in the same function, and the functionality looks generic (findParent), so maybe a Java programmer will know what it is about on the instant.

A breaking issue has been posted [here](https://github.com/Sable/matjuice/issues/12) more than a year ago and it doesn't seem the authors are willing to correct it. That is why I am asking here.

Bellow are the two errors :

```
[javac] /home/geoffrey/mclab-core/languages/Natlab/src/natlab/utils/NodeFinder.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         .filter(n -> clazz.isInstance(n) || n.getParent() == null)
[javac]                                              ^
[javac]   symbol:   method getParent()
[javac]   location: variable n of type Object
```

```
[javac] /home/geoffrey/mclab-core/languages/Natlab/src/natlab/utils/NodeFinder.java:66: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to T
[javac]         .orElse(null);
[javac]                ^
[javac]   where T is a type-variable:
[javac]     T extends Object declared in method <T>findParent(Class<T>,ASTNode<?>)
```

Bellow is the related piece of code (the errors occur on line 3 and 7 in this extract)

```java
public static <T> T findParent(Class<T> clazz, ASTNode<?> node) {
  return Stream.iterate(node, ASTNode::getParent)
      .filter(n -> clazz.isInstance(n) || n.getParent() == null)
      .findFirst()
      .filter(clazz::isInstance)
      .map(clazz::cast)
      .orElse(null);
}
```

The complete file is [here](https://github.com/Sable/mclab-core/blob/master/languages/Natlab/src/natlab/utils/NodeFinder.java) (there are helpful comments in the file) along with the rest of the repo.

I tried to give it a go myself but with zero knowledge of Java, it is just too abstract for me to debug.

Answer (score 1):

These errors are come out because of compiler doesn't know what `ast.ASTNode` is. There is no such class in the project. But there is `Natlab.gen` target from ant build file:

```
mclab-core/languages/Natlab/build.xml
```

Try to run `Natlab.gen` target and the directory `gen` (that contains necessary package `ast.ASTNode`) will be generated inside `Natlab` directory. This should fix compilation errors.

Comment: Ohhh this makes sense to me. Out of curiosity, I checked the content of the `bin-ant` directory in which the build command is supposed to create files and noticed there actually was an `ast` directory and an `ASTNode.class` file in there. Just to be sure, I emptied `bin-ant` and attempted to build again. They are added to this folder. I am not sure if it means the compiler knows about ast.ASTNode or not.

Comment: I ran `ant gen` and `ant Natlab.gen` (is this what you meant by "try to run [...]"?) which completed without errors but it doesn't change the output of `ant build` in the Terminal. I must say I didn't mention something in my original post : there are a lot of warnings about deprecated code (`deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated`), 93 to be precise, and they are all about files contained in the `ast` directory. They also all concern a function named `fullCopy` (more details in the next comment).

Comment: It is worth saying ASTNode is concerned. Here is the warning : `[javac] /home/geoffrey/mclab-core/languages/Natlab/gen/ast/ASTNode.java:979: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
    [javac]   public ASTNode<T> fullCopy() {`

Comment: @geoffrey `ant gen` command has to create a new directory named `gen`, that will contain all necessary classes. To make sure, you can remove `gen` directory and run `ant gen` again. Also don't worry about warnings, since this code is seems to be a legacy code..

Comment: I just did that, I also tried deleting both directories. `ant gen` and `ant Natlab.gen` always complete successfully (whatever the order I run them), but `ant build` still gives me the exact same output.

Comment: @geoffrey I have tried to reproduce this issue one more time using IntelliJ IDE, java8 and to my surprise it was successfully built. So one `jar` file was generated and I uploaded it to google drive. You can get it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jkoDQ1XnTdokYBPZLCQkRAfFB4NMw2C6)

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks. Can you post your setup as a distinct answer so I can accept it? I also realized a couple of hours ago that there actually are ready-made jars and python scripts in the [releases page](https://github.com/Sable/matjuice/releases)... Why they are not mentioned in the readme is beyond me, but in any case it is critical to be able to edit and rebuild the tool because some MatLab features are said to not have yet been implemented.